# LINQ - GroupBy and consolidate

Tags: linq

Given

```
class Row
{
   public int CustomerId;
   public decimal Purchase;
}
```

What's the easiest way to get another collection with total purchases by customer. Basically a GroupBy plus the purchases added.

```
rows.GroupBy(r => r.CustomerId);
```

Performance is not a factor as the collections are fairly small.

**EDIT**
Suppose the Row class has several properties and I want the grouped result to be a specific type, not anonymous.

```
class Row
{
   public int CustomerId;
   public decimal Purchase;
   public string SomeProp1;
   public double SomeProp2;
   public long SomeProp3;
}

class TotalsRow
{
   public int CustomerId;
   public decimal TotalPurchases;
   public string SomeProp1;
   public double SomeProp2;
   public long SomeProp3;
}
```

**EDIT2**
Just realized the previous edit makes no sense since I'm consolidating several rows. What I'm actually looking for is to include properties that are equal to all rows within a group. Assuming all of the above properties except Purchase fulfill this requirement, this is the solution I came up with.

```
rows.GroupBy(r => r.CustomerId)
    .Select(g => new TotalsRow()
                {
                    CustomerId= g.Key, 
                    TotalPurchases = g.Sum(gr => gr.Purchase),
                    SomeProp1 = g.First().SomeProp1);
                    SomeProp2 = g.First().SomeProp2);
                    SomeProp3 = g.First().SomeProp3);
                }
       );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
rows.GroupBy(
    r => r.CustomerId,
    r => r.Purchase,
    (id, group) => new
        {
            CustomerId = id,
            SumPurchase = group.Sum()
        }
)
```

**Update**:
Of course, assume that `SomeProp1-3` are the same for all rows with equal CustomerId.

*First variant (Row -> Row)*:

```
rows.GroupBy(
    r => r.CustomerId,
    r => r,
    (id, group) => group.Aggregate((result, row) =>
        { result.Purchase += row.Purchase; return result; })
)
```

*Second variant (Row -> TotalsRow)*:

```
rows.GroupBy(
    r => r.CustomerId,
    r => r,
    (id, group) =>
    {
        var first = group.First();
        return new TotalsRow
        {
            CustomerId = id,
            TotalPurchases = group.Sum(r => r.Purchase),
            SomeProp1 = first.SomeProp1,
            SomeProp2 = first.SomeProp2,
            SomeProp3 = first.SomeProp3
        };
    }
)
```

Comment: Works, although I'd rather instantiate a new Row.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'm still struggling with Aggregate so the second variant seems more readable to me.

Answer (score 2):

You're close.  `GroupBy` returns a collection with a `Key` Property and an enumerator that loops through the items within that group:

```
rows.GroupBy(r => r.CustomerId)
    .Select(g => new {
                    Customer = g.Key, 
                    TotalPurchases = g.Sum(gr => gr.Purchase)
                    }
           );
```

Comment: Since the schema of the result doesn't differ from the entity, you could instantiate new `Row`s in the `Select`.

Comment: Doesn't compile ('g' doesn't exist). Also, as Jeffery pointed out, instead of using an anonymous type instantiating new rows would be better. The actual 'row' has quite a few properties.

Comment: @D Stanley Yup, that works, thanks. I ended up using Vladimir's version but because you can't accept two different answers, I accepted his even though your's works just as well.